# make for ( rowIdx = 1...) work using cuda threads

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have this in c++

```
for ( rowIdx = 1; rowIdx < (NbRows - 1); rowIdx++ )
```

In order to do it using cuda ,how should I handle it?

Because in cuda we do:

```
if (rowIdx < ArraySize) ...
```

If I set `rowIdx=1` before calling `if (rowIdx < ArraySize)` , it doesn't work.

----UPDATE ----------------------------

A simple example for illustration.

```
__global__ void test_func(int *a_in,int *b_in,int *c_out)
{

    size_t rowIdx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    rowIdx=1;

    if (rowIdx <ARRAY_SIZE) 
      c_out[rowIdx]=a_in[rowIdx]*b_in[rowIdx];


    }

//fill matrices
for (int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++){

      a_in[i]=i;
      b_in[i]=i+1;
      c_out[i]=0;

     }
```

If I use `rowIdx=1` ,then I am taking only the first result correctly.The rest are zeros.

Comment: Did you read [that](http://www.training.prace-ri.eu/uploads/tx_pracetmo/GPSMEToolkitIntro.pdf) and try [this](http://code.google.com/p/c2cudatranslator/) ?

Comment: What does mean `it doesn't work`. Can you show what you've already tried? There are so many questions relating to your topic - I have a for loop, how can I convert it to cuda!

Comment: @hubs:As I said,If I try setting rowIdx=1 before the if statement,I am not getting the results I should.I just tested in a small example doing multiplication a[i]*b[i].

Comment: Than please post your complete small example! Because with your delivered facts, `rowIdx = 1; ... if (rowIdx < ArraySize) ...` I don't see why that shouldn't work. So I assume your problem has another reason.

Comment: Why do you want to write `rowIdx = 1`? That doesn't make any sense! All threads will compute the same index - `c_out[1] = a_in[1] * b_in[i]`. All other elements of `c_out` will be undefined/garbage.

Comment: @hubs:Yes, I know,but that's how it is in the cpp.I want to do the same in cuda though.The example is just for showing the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple replace of a for loop with the given functionality provided in your example, a kernel can looks this way.

```
__global__ void test_func(int *a_in,int *b_in,int *c_out)
{
    size_t rowIdx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 

    if (rowIdx > 0 &&       // ensure that rowIdx is at least 1
        rowIdx <ARRAY_SIZE) // ensure that rowIdx is not out of bounds
    {
      c_out[rowIdx]=a_in[rowIdx]*b_in[rowIdx];
    }
}
```

All threads will compute different array elements starting from index `1` to `ARRAY_SIZE-1`.
Be aware that the "real" first element `c_out[0]` won't be computed in this case.

Comment: :Excellent!Thanks!(Ok, for the c_out[0])